# Replacement for Microsoft's USB Device Simulation Framework (DSF) 

Tags: tools, hardware

I am looking for a replacement to Microsoft's USB Device Simulation Framework (DSF) which is deprecated on the Windows 7 WDK, especially for one supporting USB 3.0

Comment: Do you have a reference that shows DSF is being deprecated? I'm surprised to hear that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/br259131.aspx
"Device Simulation Framework (DSF)
Device Simulation Framework has been deprecated from the WDK."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an alternative would be to plug in a number of physical USB audio devices and then programmatically "unplug" and "replug" them: [Simulate USB unplug/replug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297304/how-to-simulate-a-usb-unplug-replug-after-the-device-is-safely-removed)

Another alternative might be to have a number of bluetooth audio devices within range and programmatically connect/disconnect them: [Programmatically connect/disconnect bluetooth headset](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/0af0e34b-4628-4839-9222-2b56c1b4bbe3)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell (now that the WDK is officially released), DSF is still available as part of the Windows 7 WDK (on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365) below the Win8 WDK downloads) - it's just been removed from the Windows 8 WDK. No idea why, because as far as I can tell, the driver model is the same, and DSF devices created in the Win7 WDK *should* work in Win8.